# How can I read data matrix better using Zxing?

Tags: java, android, opencv

In this case, I want to read data matrices from an image by using Zxing but it cannot read some of them. Which kinds of image processing methods are more effective to solve this problem? Please, help me to solve this.

[image: Here is the example data matrix case.]

Comment: Ain't this a qr code?

Comment: @DavidInnocent , No it isnt, but both of data matrix and qr code are two-dimensional barcodes so they are look like each other.

Comment: you're close to the limit of resolution with that picture (Nyquist goes for 2D as well). I'd recommend better optics rather than trying to work with marginal sensor data. I hope you're in a position where you have the choice.